# 'unraw' a string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, escaping, unicode-escapes, rawstring

How can I take a raw string in JavaScript and convert all the escape sequences to their respective characters? In other words, the reverse of `String.raw`. For example:

```
unraw("\\x61\\x62\\x63 \\u{1F4A9} \\u0041");
// => "abc  A";
```

I tried `JSON.parse`, however it only supports the last format (`\\u0041`). Neither `unescape` nor `decodeURI` are what I am looking for at all.

Answer (score 3):

I think you basically have three choices:

1. Write your own function to do it, handling the various types of escapes that JavaScript allows in strings; or
2. Leverage the JavaScript parser built into the JavaScript engine where this code is running, which means trusting the content of the string since you have to use `new Function` (or even `eval`) to do it, which means opening yourself up to arbitrary code execution; or
3. Use a parser like [Esprima](https://esprima.org) or similar

#1 is a bit of a pain but really not **that** bad, there aren't that many to handle. #2 has all the usual issues around trusting the string contents not to be nefarious code, since using `eval` or calling the function `new Function` creates allows arbitrary code execution. #3 is a fairly heavy solution.

Looking at #1 a bit more closely, [EscapeSequence](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#prod-EscapeSequence) breaks down into:

- Single character escapes, `\` followed by one of `'"\bfnrtv`.
- Hex escapes, `\xHH` where `H` is a hex digit
- Unicode escapes, `\uHHHH` or `\u{H+)` where, again, `H` is a hex digit

That's not actually all that bad. Here's a quick-and-dirty:

```js
// Note: This does not implement LegacyOctalEscapeSequence (https://tc39.es/ecma262/#prod-annexB-LegacyOctalEscapeSequence)
function unraw(str) {
    return str.replace(/\\[0-9]|\\['"\bfnrtv]|\\x[0-9a-f]{2}|\\u[0-9a-f]{4}|\\u\{[0-9a-f]+\}|\\./ig, match => {
        switch (match[1]) {
            case "'":
            case "\"":
            case "\\":
                return match[1];
            case "b":
                return "\b";
            case "f":
                return "\f";
            case "n":
                return "\n";
            case "r":
                return "\r";
            case "t":
                return "\t";
            case "v":
                return "\v";
            case "u":
                if (match[2] === "{") {
                    return String.fromCodePoint(parseInt(match.substring(3), 16));
                }
                return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(match.substring(2), 16));
            case "x":
                return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(match.substring(2), 16));
            case "0":
                return "\0";
            default: // E.g., "\q" === "q"
                return match.substring(1);
        }
    });
}
console.log(String.raw`${unraw("\\x61\\x62\\x63 \\u{1F4A9} \\u0041")}`);
// Double-check result
const str =           "\x61\x62\x63 \u{1F4A9} \u0041";
const raw = String.raw`\x61\x62\x63 \u{1F4A9} \u0041`;
console.log(str === unraw(raw));
```

I'm sure that can be cleaned up a bit.

Comment: I think #1 is probably the way to go. I'm surprised this doesn't exist already; I was hoping to find a well-tested library for this. #2 is definitely not an option as I have no idea what the string content will be. This is for an NPM module involving template literal tags so that would be a huge vulnerability.

Comment: @Ian - Yeah, I was surprised not to find one. I realized that #1 isn't really that much work at all, string literals aren't that complicated. I added a quick-and-dirty version.

Comment: Oops, I missed a couple of things (as you do). Fixed now I hope.

Comment: Thank you! I expanded on that idea a bit and came up with something that hopefully behaves almost exactly like a JS parser (notably I wanted it to throw errors for invalid sequences). I've posted a link in my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/57332315/1243041

Answer (score 0):

As it appears there's nothing out there, I've written my own, which is a bit more robust than @T.J. Crowder's excellent answer. Notably, I wanted a function that behaves pretty much exactly as the JS parsers process strings, which means it needs to error on invalid codes. This function also properly handles double-escaped sequences like `"\\\x61"` which should yield `"\\x61"` and Unicode surrogates, as well as optionally handling octal literals properly or at least throwing errors when encountering them. Finally it supports escaping characters that don't need to be escaped, like `"\R"`.

I haven't had the chance to test it thoroughly yet, but I've uploaded it here https://github.com/iansan5653/unraw and will eventually write extensive unit tests and publish it as an NPM module.

Comment: Great! But on SO, the code has to be **in** the answer, not just linked.

Comment: OK, I'll clean it up and get a smaller example in the answer